# Does such ring extension exist?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Does there exist a commutative ring extension $A\subsetneq B$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $A$ is a normal local domain and $B$ is a regular domain with the same dimension;
2. $A$ and $B$ have the same fraction field;
3. $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra.

Comment: Hi. You can take $B = k[x,y]$ polynomial ring over a field, and $A = k[x,xy]$. Since $y = xy/x$, they have the same field of fractrions, these two rings are regular (so normal), and $A[y] \to B$ gives item 3.

Comment: Hi. We need $A$ to be local.

Comment: You can localize $A, B$ at the complement of the maxial ideal $(x,xy)A$.